# url_like in graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I guess there is no answers for my question, but i want try anyway :)

I'm moving my app from the V1 API to the V2. (i'm using the Facebook PHP SDK but this is not important). As the FQL is now deprecated, i want to remove all my previous code that used it.

The last thing i can't perform with the graph API is an old call to the url_like FQL table : i just want to see if the user likes a given URL (which is not a Facebook page) or not.

Is there anyway to do it without FQL ?

Thanks !

Comment: i am pretty sure it´s not possible anymore, but why do you want to know the url likes anyway? what for?

Comment: @luschn I have multile likes button to show, but one by one, at different moment. So i want to know which one are already liked or not, to know which one i have to show.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the Graph API afaik. BUT: Never try to hide Like Buttons because the user liked something already. The user should always be able to unlike at the exact same location where he liked something.

Comment: Thank you. In this case you're right, but i have no choice :) But it still a bad thing that it's no longer possible :s

Comment: you always have a choice ;)